# Marble Test of MergeMap with Promises Produces no Output

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, rxjs

I have an observable `source`, and a function `f` which turns `source` elements into `Promise`s. I want to apply that function to the `source` and write a test for that, using chai:

```
import { TestScheduler } from 'rxjs/testing/TestScheduler';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/mergeAll';
// expect is from chai

const marbles = new TestScheduler((a, b) => expect(a).to.deep.equal(b));
const source = marbles.createColdObservable('a-a-a-a');
const map = source.mergeMap(async a => a);
marbles.expectObservable(map).toBe('a-a-a-a');
marbles.flush();
```

The expected result is for the test to pass. The actual result is:

```
AssertionError: expected [] to deeply equal [ Array(4) ]
```

Why is the observable empty?

Comment: There must be something not really perfect in `expectObservable` when it has to work with Promises. If you substitute `async a => a` with `a => Observable.of(a)` everything works. But unfortunately it is not your case. By the way, why do you want to transform the elements emitted by `source` into Promises?

Comment: I don't want to transform them into promises, I'm mapping them through a function that does something that comes back as a promise (i.e. a web request using an API).
So this seems to be a bug in `expectObservable`? The curious thing is that it shouldn't care that there are promises. What it gets is a stream of values after `mergeMap`, not promises!

Comment: Yes, it looks like a but to me, even if I am not 100%. The reason is that if you substitute the function which returns a Promise with a function that returns an Observable, everything works. I have tried to dig a bit into the code, but is was not easy to understand, so I gave up.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, it turns out Promises cant be tested as you would expect.

see this page for more details
https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/guide/testing/marble-testing

In summary:

**Known Issues**

You can't directly test RxJS code that consumes Promises or uses any of the other schedulers (e.g. AsapScheduler)

```
// Some RxJS code that also consumes a Promise, so TestScheduler won't be able
// to correctly virtualize and the test will always be really async
const myAsyncCode = () => from(Promise.resolve('something'));

it('has async code', done => {
  myAsyncCode().subscribe(d => {
    assertEqual(d, 'something');
    done();
  });
});
```